# handling files with multiple "." in filename boost::filesystem::stem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

If filename is "abc.def.xyz", how do I get ".def.xyz" as extension and "abc" as stem. I understand `boost::filesystem::stem/extension()` considers the right most "." as the delimiter between file name and extension. Can I somehow change it to left-most "." ?

Related question, but looking for answer with right-most "."
[boost filename extension with multiple "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765714/boost-filename-extension-with-multiple/5785092#5785092)

Comment: Do a regular string parse. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235133 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133103/85371 if you plan on checking suffixes a lot